# NSMutableDictionary key not finding object

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have the following method in my iOS application. The statement:

```
GMSMarker *marker = [places objectForKey:place];
```

does not always find the object for the key, when I definitely know there is an object to be found.

The method is:

```
- (void)removePlacesOfType:(AmenityType)type {
NSMutableArray* objectsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (Place *place in places) {
        if (place.type == type) {
            GMSMarker *marker = [places objectForKey:place];
            NSLog(@"%@ /// %@",place, marker);
            marker.map = nil;
            [objectsToRemove addObject:place];
        }
    }
    [places removeObjectsForKeys:objectsToRemove];
}
```

Updated to include object dump:

```
2013-10-28 13:11:20.988 Trancierge[12881:70b] **Pre For-Loop

2013-10-28 13:11:20.989 Trancierge[12881:70b] Markers built: 16
2013-10-28 13:11:20.989 Trancierge[12881:70b] <GMSMarker: 0x1b29cd30> (null) (-27.475179, 153.016384), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.989 Trancierge[12881:70b] <GMSMarker: 0x1b2b3550> (null) (-27.477081, 153.012322), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.990 Trancierge[12881:70b] <GMSMarker: 0x1b27d9c0> (null) (-27.477321, 153.012479), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.990 Trancierge[12881:70b] <GMSMarker: 0x1b2b2d80> (null) (-27.477032, 153.013461), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.990 Trancierge[12881:70b] <GMSMarker: 0x1b27d6f0> (null) (-27.474801, 153.016204), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.990 Trancierge[12881:70b] <GMSMarker: 0x1b27deb0> (null) (-27.476008, 153.013956), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.990 Trancierge[12881:70b] <GMSMarker: 0x1b27e0b0> (null) (-27.476420, 153.012121), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.991 Trancierge[12881:70b] <GMSMarker: 0x1b27e2e0> (null) (-27.477069, 153.012231), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.991 Trancierge[12881:70b] <GMSMarker: 0x1b27e510> (null) (-27.477887, 153.012734), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.991 Trancierge[12881:70b] <GMSMarker: 0x1b27e740> (null) (-27.477337, 153.012621), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.991 Trancierge[12881:70b] <GMSMarker: 0x1b27e970> (null) (-27.475651, 153.013364), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.992 Trancierge[12881:70b] <GMSMarker: 0x1b27eba0> (null) (-27.477033, 153.013458), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.992 Trancierge[12881:70b] <GMSMarker: 0x1b27edd0> (null) (-27.476088, 153.016655), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.992 Trancierge[12881:70b] <GMSMarker: 0x1b27f000> (null) (-27.475618, 153.016321), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.992 Trancierge[12881:70b] <GMSMarker: 0x1b27f240> (null) (-27.477225, 153.016497), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.992 Trancierge[12881:70b] <GMSMarker: 0x1b27f480> (null) (-27.477740, 153.012813), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>

2013-10-28 13:11:20.993 Trancierge[12881:70b] **In For-Loop

2013-10-28 13:11:20.993 Trancierge[12881:70b] <Place: 0x1b2bce90> /// (null)
2013-10-28 13:11:20.993 Trancierge[12881:70b] <Place: 0x1b2b5100> /// <GMSMarker: 0x1b2b3550> (null) (-27.477081, 153.012322), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.993 Trancierge[12881:70b] <Place: 0x1b2b2d60> /// (null)
2013-10-28 13:11:20.993 Trancierge[12881:70b] <Place: 0x1b27d630> /// (null)
2013-10-28 13:11:20.993 Trancierge[12881:70b] <Place: 0x1b27d7e0> /// (null)
2013-10-28 13:11:20.994 Trancierge[12881:70b] <Place: 0x1b27df90> /// (null)
2013-10-28 13:11:20.994 Trancierge[12881:70b] <Place: 0x1b27e1c0> /// (null)
2013-10-28 13:11:20.994 Trancierge[12881:70b] <Place: 0x1b27e3f0> /// (null)
2013-10-28 13:11:20.994 Trancierge[12881:70b] <Place: 0x1b27e620> /// <GMSMarker: 0x1b27e510> (null) (-27.477887, 153.012734), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.994 Trancierge[12881:70b] <Place: 0x1b27e850> /// (null)
2013-10-28 13:11:20.994 Trancierge[12881:70b] <Place: 0x1b27ea80> /// <GMSMarker: 0x1b27e970> (null) (-27.475651, 153.013364), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.995 Trancierge[12881:70b] <Place: 0x1b27ecb0> /// <GMSMarker: 0x1b27eba0> (null) (-27.477033, 153.013458), <UIImage: 0x9e45680>
2013-10-28 13:11:20.995 Trancierge[12881:70b] <Place: 0x1b27eee0> /// (null)
2013-10-28 13:11:20.995 Trancierge[12881:70b] <Place: 0x1b27f120> /// (null)
2013-10-28 13:11:20.995 Trancierge[12881:70b] <Place: 0x1b27f360> /// (null)
2013-10-28 13:11:20.995 Trancierge[12881:70b] <Place: 0x1b27f5a0> /// (null)
```

Comment: Given this bit of code `if (place.type == type)`, it makes sense for `GMSMarker *marker = [places objectForKey:place];` to not always find the object given that sometimes that line of code won't even execute, right?  But even if it always executes, how are you positive there is an object at that key?

Comment: Moreover, you say it `does not always find the object`, which implies that it does at least part of the time find the object, right?  Is there any pattern between the objects it does and doesn't find?

Comment: place is an instance of class  AmenityType?

Comment: Another method creates the place and marker and adds them to the dictionary at the same time. I have tested this method thoroughly to ensure that the entries are being saved, and they are. For testing, i have only been creating Places of one type of amenity, so the method should find all objects within the object places (which is of type NSMutableDictionary)

Comment: @MirkoCatalano place is an instance of Place, which has an instance variable (AmenityType)type. AmenityType is a simple enum.

Comment: If you print the dictionary can you able to see the object which has been added? In removePlacesOfType context?

Comment: @nhgrif Basically, the system does a Google Places search of local coffee shops and creates a place for each one it finds. I am doing the search on the exact same location and the exact some places are being created. The markers found / not found are random each time.

Comment: @san if i write the NSMutableDictionary at the start of removePlacesOfType: the dictionary shows all objects are accounted for.

Comment: So the place object instance in your dictionary and the 'place' which you are finding out from a "for loop" are they same?

As you might aware when you add an object to dictionary, it should comply to NSCopying Protocol

Comment: @San My understanding of the "for loop" is that it uses "fast enumeration" and passes the memory address, instead of a new object.

Comment: NSLog places to verify the input. Move the current log above the if.

Comment: @Zaph partial output:

`2013-10-28 13:01:55.163 Trancierge[12824:70b] <Place: 0x9ea4440> /// <GMSMarker: 0x9ea4360> (null) (-27.475618, 153.016321), <UIImage: 0xa77dc50>
2013-10-28 13:01:55.164 Trancierge[12824:70b] <Place: 0x9e85fc0> /// <GMSMarker: 0x9e93a80> (null) (-27.477033, 153.013458), <UIImage: 0xa77dc50>
2013-10-28 13:01:55.164 Trancierge[12824:70b] <Place: 0x9e65540> /// (null)`

You can see the "unfound" (null) marker object.

Comment: Obvious it won't create a new object though. But when you add an object to a dictionary and the 'key' is your custom object then that object should comply to NSCoping Protocol and will create a new instance of your 'place' object as a key by default.

Comment: If that is the case then implement protocol in a subclass of 'place' - (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone and return self

Comment: @San the Place class does confirm to the NSCopying protocol. It creates a copy of the object... are you saying it should return itself instead?

Comment: Changing the copyWithZone: method to return self solved the issue. As it's a comment, I don't know how to credit @san with the solution.

Comment: Alright I have added it to answers as well so that others get to know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Key added to NSDictionary should always conform to NSCopying Protocol. And the default implementation will create a new instance of key object (Place in your case).

Solution is to conform and implement the protocol NSCopying in your 'Place' custom class and return self. So that the key instance is same everywhere.

```
- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
   return self;
}
```

Comment: Also, if you override `-isEqual:` you must override `-hash`! This is important for collections, especially if your objects will be dictionary keys!